# What do you call this type of UI Element?

Tags: user-interface

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong forum, however I've been googling all afternoon as to what one would call this type of UI element (see attached picture). I know the inverse of this is what is called a card, however am stumped regarding this one - what do you call this little "canyon" in UI?

[image]

Comment: What is it's purpose?

Comment: It's purpose is purely to look nice.

Comment: Then it's just a box or a pane.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any keywords to describe the specific "depth" aspect of the pane/box shown here though? When I try to find more information regarding boxes and panes, I have a hard time finding this aspect specifically

Comment: if you are looking for a component name or such, I think you should focus on the semantic purpose of the component you are rendering, not how it looks. However, this type of border is sometimes called an 'inset' border. (See CSS `border-style: inset`).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @Evert! You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it or I can close this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230430/discussion-between-elliot-solskjaer-and-evert).

Comment: Sure I'll leave it as an answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style of border is sometimes called an 'inset' border. (See CSS `border-style: inset`).